# Send a value in POST request that is inside a **Promise** JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, post, promise

I have a simple form in `html` that looks like this:

```
<form method="post" id="postImageForm" action="storeImage.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="image" id="image-tag">
    <button class="capture-button" type="submit" value="submit"></button>
</form>
```

and a `Javascript eventListner` :

```
PostForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    
    e.preventDefault();
    let imageTag = document.getElementById('image-tag');
    html2canvas(displayScreen).then(canvas=>{
        imageTag.value = canvas.toDataURL();
        appendThumbnail(canvas.toDataURL());
        console.log("inside the promise: "+imageTag.value) //valid results.
    });
    console.log("outside the promise: "+imageTag.value); //empty results.
})
```

my ***php*** file receives empty value and so is my `console.log()` outside the **promise** scope.

How can it be fixed to send the value into `POST`?

Comment: `my php file receives empty value`...where are you actually sending anything to PHP here? Your code disables the default postback behaviour, but I don't see anything which would replace it (e.g. JS to submit the form, or an AJAX request)

Comment: at the form part ```action=storeImage.php```

Comment: Again, your JS code  (`e.preventDefault()`) disables the default postback behaviour, so unless the JS code is erroring, or the event listener is never actually bound, this should not be sending anything to the server at all. Have you checked the console for errors or used the JS debugger to check anything like that?

Comment: I removed the ***preventDefault*** command and still my php file when it executed, it’s $_POST have an empty value for the key

Comment: To add to this @ADyson the php file only have ```print_r ($_POST)``` and this results with empty value for the key **image**

Comment: Well obviously it will, because you're posting back the form, so the JavaScript never runs. I suggest keeping `e.preventDefault()`, and inside the `.then =>....` callback, after you've written the data to the image field, you can use JS to submit the form (should just be `document.getElementById("postImageForm").submit()`). Or if you prefer not to post back the entire page, you can implement an AJAX call.